# br html tag is not working in helper file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Here is the code I have in my helper file but it is not working:

```
link_to objs.try(:send,:name) , eval("edit_#{objs.try(:class).try(:name).try(:downcase)}_path(objs,action_name: action)") , remote: true,style: "color:  #{colour_picker_title objs.class.name.downcase} !important", data_toggle: "tooltip" ,class: "tooltip-class", title: ( get_right_by_role("delete_#{objs.class.name.downcase}_progress",objs.class.name.downcase) ? (objs.try(:send,:progresses).order("created_at DESC").limit(3).map{|pr| "#{pr.created_at.try(:strftime,"%d-%m-%Y")} : #{pr.description} <br>".html_safe}rescue "") : "")
```

How to add line break after this:

```
map{|pr| "#{pr.created_at.try(:strftime,"%d-%m-%Y")} : #{pr.description} <br>".html_safe}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add \n line break after map like this:

```
map{|pr| "#{pr.created_at.try(:strftime,"%d-%m-%Y")} : #{pr.description}"}.join("\n")
```

This will add the line break.